# Power Query replace values (enter step for potential future occurrence)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

In the Power Query editor of Power BI I try to enter a replace value step for something that currently does not exist in the table. But I know that future versions of the table will include the thing that I will have to replace. However the editor gives me an error message because in the current version of the table that string I want to replace is not there. How can I solve this?

In detail it is a CSV file (daily updated) that from time to time will contain values that include a "thousands separator" (`,` in my case) and that "," I will have to replace by "" when it occurs.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem either. Copy below query into the Advanced Editor and see yourself.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(
        Json.Document(
            Binary.Decompress(
                Binary.FromText(
                    "i45WMjQ0MNYzNFWK1YlWMjIwMNCzNAGzTSwszcEMQz0jY6BQLAA=", 
                    BinaryEncoding.Base64
                ), 
                Compression.Deflate
            )
        ), 
        let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [number = _t]
    ),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        Source,",","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"number"}),
    #"Changed Type with Locale" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
            #"Replaced Value", 
            {{"number", type number}}, 
            "en-US"
        )
in
    #"Changed Type with Locale"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It worked in code directly. I must have mixed up something while using the editor/masks.

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't seem right. If you replace a string that does not exist then it just does nothing, it does not generate an error. Post your code if you want us to look at it otherwise potentially surround your code line with  **try** and **otherwise**. Look it up